# Can we move the "Translate this page" menu to be inside the Communication site top navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, administration, communication-site

We have the following communication site collection inside our SharePoint online tenant, which have the "Translate this page" menu as follow:

[image]

So my question is if we can move the "Translate this page" menu to be inside the Communication site top navigation? as shown above?

Comment: Is "Translate this page" control custom solution or OOTB multilingual feature?

Comment: @GaneshSanap it is the OOTB multilingual feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to move the "Translate this page" option to be inside the communication site top navigation using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

Site navigation can only have link or label/heading in navigation.